# How to reverse Stripe's cancel_at for their subscriptions in the API?

Tags: api, stripe-payments

I understand how to cancel a subscription with Stripe's `cancel_at` attribute, but how exactly do you reverse it? For example, we have an "Auto Renew" toggle switch on the Billing page which essentially turns it on and off. It seems like, With Stripe's API, there's no way to turn it back off, only on? Seems very odd.

Here's how I'm canceling a subscription 1 year from today:

```
Stripe::Subscription.update(sub.id, {cancel_at: 5.years.from_now.to_time.to_i})
```

however, I've tried some random things to *reverse* the effect, but seems impossible. I've tried the following with no luck:

```
Stripe::Subscription.update(sub.id, {cancel_at: nil})
```

With this, I get no error and it seems like it works, but the Stripe UI still shows the cancellation date is 5 years from now.

```
Stripe::Subscription.update(sub.id, {cancel_at: 0})
```

Have tried this as well, but no luck because it requires an integer.

Is the only way to avoid canceling a subscription that's scheduled to cancel is to cancel it and create a new one?

It's a little confusing because there's a "Don't cancel" button on their web interface, but doesn't seem to be a way to do this via API.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just tried `cancel_at_period_end: false` and that seems to have done the trick. So weird:

```
Stripe::Subscription.update(
  sub.id,
  { cancel_at_period_end: false }
)
```

Comment: Just confirmed this works for me as well.